# Не работают слоты/сигналы

Tags: c++, qt

1. Помогите разобраться. MainWindow::on_push_autorisation_clicked() - при нажатии на кнопку отправляется сигнал. В слоте выводим текст и отправляем сигнал дальше.
   Если не отправлять сигнал все ок работает. Не блочиться гуи и выводится текст. Но если отправить сигнал (раскомментировать) - ничего не выводиться и гуи блокируется, но сигнал вроде как проходит.

```
    signals:
        void send_input_data(const std::string&, const std::string&, int);
       
    private slots:
        void on_push_autorisation_clicked();
     
    void MainWindow::on_push_autorisation_clicked()
    {
       
     
    ui->text_output->append(QString("clicked"));
        auto logon = ui->logon->text();
        auto psw = ui->password->text();
        auto room = ui->room_id->text();
        ui->text_output->append(QString("send signal"));
       
        //emit send_input_data(logon.toStdString(), psw.toStdString(), room.toUInt());
    }
```

2. connect работает только если код ниже в одном потоке. как только раскомментирую - не работает. в чем может быть причины?

```
     QObject::connect(&client, SIGNAL(send_text(const std::string&, const std::string&)),
                             this, SLOT(text_from_client(const std::string&, const std::string&)));
            io_service.run();
            //std::thread th([&io_service]() { io_service.run(); });
            //th.join();
```

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте  [mcve]

Comment: интерфейс блокируется, потому что поток начинает выполнятся в главном потоке. А во втором случае Вы смешиваете буст с Qt. Хотя сам Qt прекрасно умеет сеть.

Comment: @KoVadim то есть, чтобы не блокировалось gui - нужно сигналы отправлять в новом треде?

Comment: нужно, что бы connect знал, что там новый поток. То есть, объект, которому будет посылаться сигнал, должен быть "перемещен в новый поток".

Comment: @KoVadim то есть это нужно настроить connect?

Comment: несвязанные вопросы следует задавать **отдельными** вопросами. оставьте, пожалуйста, один вопрос, внеся правку (нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса)

Comment: Ваш код с потоком рабочий, но есть нюанс, например, если контекст потока не переключится с текущего на ваш th после создания th, то остается текущий и дальше вызывается th,join(), и ваш поток th будет ждать завершение текущего (видимо гуишного, то есть основного потока приложения) - попробуйте убрать th.join() - зачем он вам? И даже если частично выполнится тело потока th, то при переключении контекста будет th.join() - и в какой-то момент ваш th уснет в неудобной позе в ожидании гуишного завершения.

Comment: а вот th.join я и не уметил.

Answer (score -1):

Ваш код с потоком рабочий, но есть нюанс, например, если контекст потока не переключится с текущего на ваш th после создания th, то остается текущий и дальше вызывается th.join(), и ваш поток th будет ждать завершение текущего (видимо гуишного, то есть основного потока приложения) - попробуйте убрать th.join() - зачем он вам? И даже если частично выполнится тело потока th, то при переключении контекста будет th.join() - и в какой-то момент ваш th уснет в неудобной позе в ожидании гуишного завершения.